# Swfit TableView load next page after scrolling to the last cell

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have tableview controller. It gets data from the api and loads page 1.
I want to go the next page when I scroll the bottom of the current page.
Is there a way to implement this?

```
      var currentPage = 1
        func loadArticles(){
            let url = "http://yazar.io/api/article/feed/" + String(currentPage)
            Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { (Request, response, json, error) -> Void in
                if (json != nil){
                    var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
                    if let data = jsonObj["articles"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
                        self.articles = data
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.view.hideLoading()
                        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MakaleCell") as MakaleTableViewCell 

        if (indexPath.row == self.articles!.count - 5) {
            currentPage += 1
            println(currentPage)
            loadArticles(currentPage: currentPage)
        }

 cell.article = self.articles?[indexPath.row]        
                return cell      
            }
```

Comment: ‘tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()‘
could help you to know if the last index is shown.

Probably, i guess you can implement the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of UITableViewDelegate and check if it's the last row.

Comment: Is it possbile to use scrollViewDidScroll?

Comment: It would be possible technically - although using `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` is to be preferred, as it is easier implemented. You should probably also display a TableViewCell with a loading indicator at the bottom of your list and show it as long as your requesting new content. This way the user will know that more content is yet to come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, extending data solved my problem...

```
self.articles?.extend(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tryied this, it looks ok. Is that work for you ?

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
var datasource = Array<Int>()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for i in 0...21
    {
        datasource.append(i)
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if indexPath.row == datasource.count-1
    {
        var max = datasource.count;
        for i in max...max+15
        {
            datasource.append(i)
        }
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I couldnt implement this to my code. I updated my question. Added an if check, when I reach the 5th cell from the bottom -> load the next page. But this code keeps loading pages back to back, because I am always at the 5th cell from the bottom.

Comment: @serdaraylanc I had the same issue where it would try to load a page multiple times. To fix it, I created a var isLoadingMore that I toggle true/false as load starts/completes and check before starting a new load.